# ImageView Send to Back Programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uiimage

After trying all the methods in the [previous post](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html)  I am not able to succeed sending my ImageView back to my Oscilloscope. I am using [aurioTouch sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html) of Apple's example in my app and I have just resized the image in that.. Now I want to have another image in the same view. In my `applicationDidFinishLaunching` in the beginning I am writing the below code

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]];
[imgView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,25,320,150)];
[view addSubview:imgView];
```

after this much of code i tried all the methods that is given in previous post but not able to get this newssmage behind the original image..

Here `view` is one of the class inherited from UIView.. How can I send new image back to my original image???

Comment: did you try oldImage.hidden = YES ?

Comment: I dont want to hide original image... I have actually resized that image and in rest of the portion i want to show new image...

Comment: did you mean new image will be shown as a background of resized image (old image ) ???

Comment: yes or atleast in the rest of the portion.

Comment: ok got it... can you provide some code that shows how are you trying to do this ?

Comment: you need to do some thing like this : first of all put your large image ... (self.view addSubView:largeImage).. then put your resized image (self.view addSubView:resizedImage).. you need to set its frame accordingly ... if large one's is (100,100,200,200) then resized's should be (150,150,100,100)...

Comment: according to your question your trying to overlap the images..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One look at the documentation for `UIView` would give you a list of possible methods to influence the view hierarchy. Some of them are:

```
– bringSubviewToFront:
– sendSubviewToBack:
– removeFromSuperview
– insertSubview:atIndex:
– insertSubview:aboveSubview:
– insertSubview:belowSubview:
– exchangeSubviewAtIndex:withSubviewAtIndex:
```

Comment: with some more changes in my app i am succeeded with 2nd method. thanx

Answer (score 5):

you need to call

```
- (void)sendSubviewToBack:(UIView *)view
```

on the view object in your code like this

```
[view sendSubviewToBack: imgView];
```

**EDIT:**

I have seen the code and from the looks of it the the image "Oscilloscope.png" is added on the EAGLView object with variable name `view` and if I am correct the you are using the same variable to add your imgView too, so I think it should work.

Comment: not working as my view is class that is inherited from UIview class

Comment: Original Image is from aurioTouch sample ie. oscilloscope.png. You can go through the sample using link from question.